# Informix query slow

Tags: performance, informix

IDS 9.04 on unix.

I got a table which has 200000+ rows ,each row has 200+ columns.
when I execute a query (supposed to return 470+ rows with 50 columns)on this table,it takes 100+ secs to return,and dbvisualizer told me :

eexecution time : 4.87 secs
fetch time : 97.56 secs

if I export all the 470+ rows into a file, the file size will less than 800K

UPDATE STATISTICS has been runned,only 50 columns selected,no blob involved ,if I select first 100 rows ,it only need 5 secs to return.

Plz help !

Comment: Which version of Informix, on which platform?  What are the conditions in the query?  What does the query plan say?  Have you run UPDATE STATISTICS?  Roughly how wide are the columns - both selected and unselected?  Are there any blobs involved?

Comment: UPDATE STATISTICS has been runned,only 50 columns selected,no blob involved ,if I select first 100 rows ,it only need 5 secs to return.

Answer (score 0):

If SELECT FIRST 100 only takes a few seconds, it suggests that the query-plan for FIRST_ROWS is dramatically different to that for ALL_ROWS.

Try running the query with SET EXPLAIN ON; both with and without the FIRST n. It might give you a clue what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

set explain on avoid_execute;

> YOUR_QUERY

set explain off;

And review the **sqexplain.out** file in your folder.